# Allow only lowest taxonomy terms to assign to nodes

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a lot of taxonomy terms that need to be categorized into multiple categories and subcategories:

```
- AAA
  - BBB
    - CCC
    - DDD
    - EEE
...
```

Is there a way how to restrict assigning higher terms to nodes (AAA, BBB) and allow to use only lowest terms (without any child terms - CCC, DDD, EEE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).

> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a
>   selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to
>   force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or
>   allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be
>   labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be
>   selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide
>   animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels
>   through Hierarchical Select!

Comment: Nice... change the widget of term reference field type in content type to Hierarchical select and set appropriate settings.